# Shape of numpy array when converting from PIL image

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, python-imaging-library

When I convert a PIL image to a numpy array using

```
image = Image.open(file_path)
image_array = numpy.array(image)
```

sometimes I get a 2D array with dimensions equal to the dimensions of the image. Other times I get a 3D array with each entry being a array of pixels (i.e. [RRR, GGG, BBB]). And other times I get a 3D array with each entry being an array with 4 values (i.e. [RRR, GGG, BBB, XXX]). What determines the shape of the numpy array? And if it's a 2D array, what do the entries represent?

Answer (score 0):

Answered my own question:

The shape of the numpy array is determined my the mode of the PIL image. The full lists of modes can be found [here](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/concepts.htm#mode). A 2D array is created when the image's mode is 1, L, or P. A 3D array is created otherwise with values analogous to the values represented by the mode.